# Partition function of multi-particle canonical ensemble

Tags: physics, integer-partitions

According to the orthogonality of function basis, Why can't the partition function be written directly as the following form
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
Z & =  \frac{1}{N!} \sum_{p_{1},p_{2}, \cdots ,p_{N}} \int { \rm{d}}^{3N} r \Psi_{p}(1,2, \cdots,N) e^{ - \frac{ \beta}{2m}(p_{1}^{2} + p_{2}^{2}+ \cdots + p_{N}^{2})}  \Psi_{p}^{*}(1,2, \cdots,N) \\
& = \frac{1}{N!} \sum_{p_{1},p_{2}, \cdots ,p_{N}} e^{ - \frac{ \beta}{2m}(p_{1}^{2} + p_{2}^{2}+ \cdots + p_{N}^{2})} \\
\end{split}
\end{align}
In fact , this form is only an approximation at high temperature.If the first-order approximation has been considered, then there will be an interaction potential.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a physics question. The reason you can't use directly the second form is that $\Psi_p$ might not be an eigenfunction of the $e^{-\frac\beta{2m}(p_1^2+p_2^2+...p_N^2)}$ operator. It is an eigenfunction if the wavefunction is completely separable, such as in the case of independent, non-interacting, particles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Am I to understand that if the system is made of independent particles, then the partition function can be written as the second form$ \frac{1}{N!} \sum_{p_{1}, \cdots, p_{N}} e^{- \frac{ \beta}{2m}( \sum_{i}p_{i}^{2})}$？

Comment: Yes. That's what your usual start point is for quantum mechanics. You then write your $\psi$ in terms of the basis of independent functions, and treat the interaction as a perturbation. But that perturbation will modify your partition function

Comment: It seems that in identical particle system(non-interaction), the partition function can't be written as the second form neither.(When $\Psi_{p}$ is the eigenfunction). I guess maybe the energy levels of Fermions and Bosons are different, so it's not rigorous to insert complete basis$ \sum_{p} \frac{1}{N!} |p \rangle \langle p|$ into partition function.(Cause $\Psi_{p}$ contains the commutative symmetry of the system, so it's not wise to integral it directly).But I don't known if I am right.:)